# Using template in a policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I'm working on importing kms keys into terraform, Unfortunately there is a big chunk of Principal resources for each sid, This principal is same for each sid. So i'm trying to use templates for the policy.

I tried :

policy.json.tpl

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-policy-1",
    "Statement": [{
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ${allowed_resources}
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ${allowed_resources}
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

main.tf

```
data "template_file" "key_policy" {
  template = file("${path.module}/policy.json.tpl")
  vars = {
    allowed_resources = var.allowed_resources
  }
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "key" {
  description = ""
  tags        = local.common_tags
  policy      = data.template_file.amp_key_policy.rendered
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "allowed_resources" {
  description = "list of all principal resources"
  type        = list(string)
  default = [
    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/a",
    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:user/b",
    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:user/c",
    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/abc,
  ]
}
```

Error:

> on main.tf line 11, in data "template_file" "key_policy":   11:
> vars = {   12:     allowed_resources = var.allowed_resources   13:   }
>
> Inappropriate value for attribute "vars": element "allowed_resources":
> string required.

Using Terraform 0.12.20

I tried passing my arn to {vars = } still getting an error. Can someone pls point out where i'm wrong.

Comment: I don't use Terraform much but take a look at the [AWS::Include Transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html)

Comment: Can you fully expand the second statement please? It's not clear what you're doing with that section.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I've updated the code, I got an error when i tried to use templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using Terraform 0.12, so you should use [the `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) instead of the `template_file` data source. A significant benefit of the `templatefile` function is that it's not limited by the Terraform 0.11 provider protocol (because it's built into the Terraform language) and so it doesn't have this limitation that the variables you set must always be strings.

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "key" {
  description = ""
  tags        = local.common_tags
  policy      = templatefile("${path.module}/policy.json.tpl", {
    allowed_resources = var.allowed_resources
  })
}
```

That won't be sufficient to work with your existing template though, because your existing template is written to just interpolate `allowed_resources` directly, but that won't work because that variable has a list value and so it needs to be encoded to a string first.

Fortunately, because you're generating JSON you can follow the advice on the `templatefile` documentation page about [Generating JSON or YAML from a template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html#generating-json-or-yaml-from-a-template), using the `jsonencode` function to let Terraform worry about producing valid JSON syntax so you can just worry about writing the data structure you need using Terraform's expression syntax:

```
${jsonencode({
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "key-policy-1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": allowed_resources
      },
      "Action": "kms:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": allowed_resources
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
})}
```

[The `jsonencode` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html) knows how to serialize all of Terraform's value types as JSON, so it will see that the `allowed_resources` references here produce lists and automatically produce JSON array syntax.

Comment: Also just wondering after importing why its showing like this, anyway to avoid it?

                      ~ Principal = {
                          ~ AWS = [
                              - "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:user/a",
                              + "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:user/b",
                              + "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:user/c",

Comment: I'm not sure but it's possible that AWS IAM is reordering the items in that array because in the IAM syntax the ordering is not significant. If so, you might need to make sure your list as given in the configuration is the same as the order returned by the AWS API so that it doesn't appear to Terraform as "drift". If that doesn't help, I'd suggest asking a new Stack Overflow question so you can share the full output and your updated configuration.